# Are http_proxy, https_proxy and so on supported on application level (vs OS level)?

Tags: linux, proxy

Do I understand correctly that all these variables are supported on the application level?

- http_proxy
- https_proxy
- ftp_proxy
- all_proxy

I mean it's not an OS-level (Linux) facility that detects the traffic on port 80 or 443 and redirects it to a proxy, but rather an application itself checks for environment variable and if it's present then they will respect it and send the traffic toward proxy?

Comment: Often it's done by a library, such as `libcurl` for C and `python-requests` for Python. So unless you're rolling your own code that uses sockets directly, it will almost always be handled automatically for you.

Comment: An exception seems to be PHP. I don't think it will respect these environment variables automatically.